# Сохранение и открытие картинки из PictureBox'a

Tags: c#

Скажите как можно открываться и сохранять картинку из PIctureBox'a, через SaveFileDialog и OpenFileDialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получение имени

```
SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
dlg.FileName = "filename";
dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt";
dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt";

Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();
if (result == true) {
    string filename = dlg.FileName;
}
```

Рисование

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(pb.Image);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
// ... Здесь рисование
pb.Image = bmp;
```

Сохранение

```
pb.Image.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: Я не совсем понял что за рисование....
В частности вот это // ... Здесь рисование

Да и ошибка в строке 
            Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();


Ошибка 1 Неявное преобразование типа "System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult" в "bool?" невозможно D:\dima\Новый год\Новый год\Form2.cs 66 37 Новый год

Comment: Рисование - это Ваши действия по рисованию на PictureBox. Вообще их может и не быть вовсе. SaveFileDialog - это Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog.

Comment: Аа понятно. А что насчет ошибки? Да и если не секрет у вас есть скайп? А то не удобно по каждому вопросу, писать сюда.

Comment: Просто я путаюсь, компилятор постоянно ругается... вот код которым я рисую в событии **Mouse_Move**

 if (paint)
            {
                SolidBrush s = new SolidBrush(colorDialog1.Color);
                g.FillEllipse (s,e.X,e.Y,Convert.ToInt32 (numericUpDown1.Value ),Convert.ToInt32 (numericUpDown2.Value ));
            }

И мне надо что бы картинка не исчезала... или есть другие способы рисования?

Answer (score 1):

```
MyImage_pb.ImageLocation = "URL";
MyImage_pb.Load();
```

---

1. MyImage_pb - обьект "картинка" (_pb - PictureBox)
2. URL - ссылка к изображению (прямой путь к изображению на компьютере тоже считается ссылкой)

Лично меня так устраивает, да и загружает таким способом всегда уверенно :)

[Больше информации о PictureBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox(v=vs.110).aspx)